# Return just the object type name without preceding "Objects."

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim objCar As Car
    objCar = New Car
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", objCar.GetType.ToString())
```

Returns this

> Objects.Car

Can I change the code slightly, without using text functions, to just return the following?

> Car

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you Try this.?

```
Dim objCar  As car
objCar  = New car
MsgBox(objCar.GetType.Name)
```

Comment: I have no idea why I didn't think of this. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just override the `ToString` method on your `Car` class?

```
public class Car
{
    public Car() {}

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Car";
    }
}
```

That way you can return whatever you want to return out of it without having to use `GetType`.

Comment: But he wants to "override" the `Type.ToString`, he doesn't want unique `ToString` for different cars.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be unique for different cars. Overriding it once on the car class and having it just return "Car" gives him the same result for any instantiated `Car`.

Comment: +1 interesting approach; I'm currently sand-pitting objects/inheritance/polymorphism so an approach like this is interesting for me. Effectively you are just borrowing one of strings methods - ToString - and giving it a new meaning...aslong as it has the same signature then the compiler is happy?

Comment: @antinescience: But it's not good-practise to override `ToString` which is an instance method as if it were a static method. `ToString` is used to return a string representation for a specific instance of this type(e.g. `BMW`) whereas `Type.ToString` describes this type(`Car`).

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I totally agree with you, but if you're not overriding `ToString` on your complex objects with something specific to that object's instantiation, doesn't it (for all intents and purposes) act like a static method? IIRC, anything inheriting `System.Object` is going to just return the object's type name - nothing changes depending on the object's properties or state. I agree that as a practice, overriding instance methods with static-esque functions is poor form, but in this case, I don't really see a negative side to it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter can you provide a small example of the problem you are describing: I'm relatively new to OOP so would be interesting for me to see